# how to use custom font in kartik mpdf?

Tags: mpdf, yii2

I'm using kartik mpdf extension and trying to style the pdf using "cssFile" property.

But any font I want to set (even from Web Safe Fonts or my oun font-face) don't effect the content of pdf file.
Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I thank you should configure cssFile and cssInline in kartik,
For example in PDF controller you have

```
public function actionPdf()
{
    $pdf = new Pdf([
        'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE, 
        'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_A4, 
        'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT, 
        'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER, 
        'content' => $contents,
        'filename' => 'Filename',
        'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.css',
        'cssInline' => '.modal-footer{text-align:left;}div.modal-body{padding:0px;}',
        'options' => ['title' => 'Devis'],
        'methods' => [ 
            'SetFooter'=>[$footer],
        ]
    ]);
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
    $headers = Yii::$app->response->headers;
    $headers->add('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
    return $pdf->render(); 
}
```

And you should go to this file in vendor folder to do what you want in css `@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.css`
And the required style (for exemple color: #fff !important) you should do that in this ligne `'cssInline' => '.modal-footer{text-align:left;}div.modal-body{padding:0px;}',`

Answer (score 2):

he asked how change font-family in pdf file.
Names of basic fonts are located in config_font.php.
You can add custom fonts in this file.

> Example

```
$this->fontdata = array( ... "pompadur" => array( 'R' => "Pompadur.ttf", ), ... )
```

paste to your html: `style="font-family: Pompadur"`